# How to use YouTube Data API v3 to search video duration with Search endpoint not Videos endpoint?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-data-api

I want to search the duration of videos with the API engine.

But I want use the `Search` API not the `Videos` API.

Like:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=nightcore&key=API_KEY&type=video`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, want you want to achieve is not possible: the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint does not return a video's [`duration`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration) property.

This behavior is in accordance with the official specs: the [response](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#response) of `Search.list` has its `items` property made of [search resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource) objects. These objects does not provide much details about the respective API resources -- videos, channels or playlists.

When you obtain, upon a `Search.list` invocation, a list of video IDs, you may well ask the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint to provide any metadata pertaining to those videos -- including the `duration` property.

Do note that the `Videos.list` endpoint accepts its request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) to be a comma-separated list of at most 50 video IDs. Also note that (irrespective of the number of actual IDs passed on to `id`) the [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) of one call to `Videos.list` is *1 unit* (very cheap).